# How to run t threads to a specific CPU?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I am new at multiprocessing. So, I have t threads and p CPU (machine threads). What I want is to equally distribute the threads into each CPU. But I am puzzling about the

I saw this documentation on how to to set the CPU affinity mask of a process indicated by the specified process id.
[os.sched_setaffinity() method](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-os-sched_setaffinity-method/#:%7E:text=sched_setaffinity()%20method%20in%20Python,available%20on%20some%20UNIX%20platforms.)

I'm currently using `multiprocessing.ThreadPool` method for threading (see the code below).

```
        pool = ThreadPool(processes=t)
        
        for j in range(t):
            threads[j] = pool.apply_async(pearson_cor, args=(j, split_x[j], y, n, len(split_x[j])))
        for j in range(t):
            correct_rs.extend(threads[j].get())
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
```

Additional questions. If I understood it correctly I need the process ID of the threads to assign specific CPU into them. Is this correct?

Also, can we get the thread process ID before running it?

Comment: It's not up to you to assign CPUs.  You just spawn off the threads you want run, and the operating system will schedule them on whatever CPUs are available.  That is its job.  Anything you do will reduce performance, by limiting the opportunities for your threads to run.

Comment: Hi @TimRoberts, yeah I know that, but  this is strictly what I want to implement in my code. I know this is possible but I am just not sure how to implement it correctly.

Comment: That is not exactly true tho. OS wouldn't know how to distribute threads on units sharing some cache, depending on their affinities. So, sure, I share your belief that Gie should not try to bother with that, and let the OS balance the threads on CPU, since whatever they would do would probably reduce performance. But one they will really know what they do, you can, on the contrary, increase performance, by taking into account the cpu/cores topology, and trying to make it match the amount of memory exchange between threads.

Comment: Hi @chrslg, thank you for your confirmation. The reason I want to do it is (1) because it is a strict requirement in my project (2) I noticed in the runs that when t = p the performance is optimal but as t increases the runtime also increases. I want to compare them with the instance that what if these threads are equally distributed in each available CPU. Also, by the way, I will only be using t - 1 CPU to give separate the process from the OS processes.

Comment: You misunderstand.  Using affinity does not mean "I own CPU 1".  It means "I cannot be scheduled on anything OTHER than CPU 1."  The operating system will keep sharing the CPUs among all ready-to-run threads (and typically there are hundreds), but yours will not be able to participate fully.  With very very few exceptions, managing affinity results in a decrease in performance.

Comment: @Tim Roberts, controlling the affinity manually is a well-known technique for performance tuning. See [this](https://passthroughpo.st/cpu-pinning-benchmarks/) for example.

Comment: There are cases, but in general it has caused far more harm than benefit.

Answer (score 1):

At least in Linux, you can set the `pid` argument of `os.sched_setaffinity()` to 0 or `threading.get_native_id()`, to change the affinity of the current thread.

If you want to do that with `ThreadPool`, do like this for example.

```
def init_worker_thread():
   masks = ...
   os.sched_setaffinity(0, masks)
pool = ThreadPool(processes=t, init_worker_thread)
```